# C++ MySQL Cannot Connect to Japanese Database Name

Tags: c++, mysql

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
using namespace std;

#define SERVER "localhost"
#define USER "root"
#define PASS "password"
#define DB "日本語"

int main(){
    MYSQL *connect;
    connect = mysql_init(NULL);
    if(!connect){
        cerr << "Error\n";
        return 1;
    }

    connect = mysql_real_connect(connect, SERVER, USER, PASS, DB, 0, NULL, 0);
    if(!connect){
        cerr << "Error\n";
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The mysql_real_connect causes the error message to be displayer. The problem is that the DB is in Japanese. I can connect perfectly fine, if I connect to a database in English.

I also tried to put DB="" and then to specify the table as db.table (i.e. 日本語.単語) but I received a segmentation fault when I tried to read from the table.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try passing an utf-8 string?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean like using a string DB instead? I tried that but you need to call DC.c_str() because mysql_real_connect requires const char*. Also the MySQL database uses the eucjpms schema not the utf-8, which may be important.

Comment: No matter which encoding you use in your database, to can use "SET NAMES" to setup utf8 encoding and mysql will do the translation. But here, the problem is to establish a connection. Try converting the wide-strings used in servername, username and dbname to utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

You probably know that but there exists different UTF encoding. I'd check the following points:

- The encoding of your .cpp file.
- Printing the DB constant as an array of byte.
- Retrieve the name of the database from the MySQL database (just connect and retrieve all db names — I guess you can do that). Compare with (2).
- Check the MySQL documentation and your database to know the encoding currently used.

Comment: I tried your suggestions. Firstly, I have no problem outputting the DB name to the standard output. Interestingly, I can connect properly to the MySQL server, when I don't specify the database name, however, when I run show tables I get: information_schema
???
mysql
performance_schema
test